# Delete historic change from a question

Tags: support

I post a question, I have to edit to remove some sensitive information, but after edit it I realize changes where still there in the historic changes. How I do to remove those historic changes?

I try delete the question and create a new one, but now say there is a duplicated question.

I want either hide the previous changes, or create a new question from scratch

Comment: _"How I do to remove those historic changes?"_ You cannot manipulate or cheat the question edit history. Edit the question again, or try to rollback for the earlier version.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want remove the historic because there was sensitve information there

Comment: FYI, it's already too late.  Change your API keys.  And don't do that again.

Answer (score 4):

Until recently:

> moderators would have to contact the Community Managers to redact private information from a post
>   <sup>**https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274**</sup>

But now:

> By going to the post revision page, mods will now see a redact option:
>   <sup>**https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274** (same post as before)</sup>

Flag your question with a custom moderator flag explaining which revision of your post contains the sensitive information, and ask for redaction.

Note that this requires two moderators, one to submit the redaction, and another to approve it.